# LDAP server set-up

Tags: server, ldap

I'd like to set up LDAP to act as central authentication of 2 web applications running on the same server.

Whats the simplest step-by-step way to go about this from scratch?

In the long run I'd also like to be able to administer the users on the system as simply as possible (think end users, not devs!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html#LDAP) answers your question.

Comment: Lots of good answers, but this tutorial got me closest to what I was after.

Answer (score 3):

because ldap is VERY hard to setup for beginners i would recommend an server configuration tool. (trust me i have spent nights to fight against openldap)
you can checkout ebox (its a server managment gui) and it configure openldap-server + samba ( windows domain logons)

Doku:
http://doc.zentyal.org/en/directory.html

Comment: That's true. I don't know any way of simplifying LDAP. It's designed to meet so many different requirements and be so flexible that it can be impossible to understand the basics. Implementations like OpenLDAP don't do administrators any favors, either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the chapter on installing and configuring an [OpenLDAP server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html) in the Ubuntu Server Guide.

Comment: The guide for setting up OpenLDAP has been broken since the Karmic Koala release and there is an unresolved bug entered about it. Look elsewhere.

Comment: This [article](http://albanianwizard.org/ubuntu-10-0-4-lucid-lynx-ldap-configuration-the-working-how-to.albanianwizard) shows how to set up a working OpenLDAP server in Ubuntu 10.04. Just don't do an ldapsearch remotely and expect to work.

Answer (score 0):

U can try all these links..

http://times.usefulinc.com/2005/09/25-ldap

http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-and-configuring-openldap-on-ubuntu-intrepid-ibex

http://www.debuntu.org/ldap-server-and-linux-ldap-clients

http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1017-ldap-client-on-ubuntu-804

Answer (score 0):

Look at this also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM_UQVVVtoY

The guy that made it, explains it fairly decent.