# Is there a simple tutorial for ldap?

Tags: ldap

I'm looking for something targeted at a complete beginner.  It's not setting up the package itself that I'm concerned with, but rather a way to set up a schema.

Comment: something like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html)

Comment: @IanN I hope that my answer was useful for you. If you think the same, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/62483).

Answer (score 2):

[An example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=28786&seqNum=2) of LDPA schema with tables, short and easy to understand.

**Skills-1st** is a website that has [this tutorial](http://www.skills-1st.co.uk/papers/ldap-schema-design-feb-2005/index.html) that have *everything* of **LDAP Schema Design**. It have a `html` version and `pdf` too for download.

Also in [the OpenLDAP website](http://www.openldap.org/) you can find software, utilities, tools, a **Quick-Start Guide** and more about the open server.

And I leave [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/2968/62483) about *set-up a LDAP server*.